# What is the proper way of displaying a cell while searching a UICollectionview

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a search feature in my `UICollectionView`. It is meant to mock the uitable view. Mock meaning look like the `UITableView` layout. I am using this just to use the springly effect like the messages app on the iOS 7.

So what I am trying to do is list title of music using the soundcloud sdk which I have already done !

This is what I have achieved so far:

[image]

But then I have implemented the various methods for searching but when I compile, I get this error:

[image]

This is my code for displaying the results:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc]
                initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 80)];
    }

    NSDictionary *track = [self.tracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, cell.bounds.size.width, 60)];
    title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Corbert-Regular" size:13];
    title.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [title setText: [track objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

    if (isSearching) {
        cell = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell = [self.tracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    }

    return cell;
}
```

p.s I use labels for song titles which is displayed on the collectionview, Is this the right way ? or there is a better way ? Because I would also love to add buttons to each cell :DD